# UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey:Any return String:Any

Tags: swift

I need  "options:(NSDictionary *)options" ,but this is "options:(NSDictionary *)options"  in swift4.1.
What should I do?

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *)options
>     NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0); // no equiv. notification. return NO if the
>     application can't open for some reason

Comment: The code is Objective-C. Please read the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what's your question about, but I'll try to guess that you're looking for `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` method. Usage example:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url) // options are equal to [:] and completionHandler is nil by default so they can be omitted
```

Here's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) for this method.